# Add all room calendars to all users outlook accounts at once

Tags: powershell, outlook-calendar

I have 200+ Office 365 users. I would like to force all the room calendars into their accounts. They have permission already to view and add meetings, but have to manually add calendar>from room list to make the calendars visible to them. I've been googling in vain to find a powershell command to add these calendars to all users at once.

Comment: I suspect you're getting downvotes as it's not a programing question, superuser would have been a better place to ask this question.

Comment: Thank you, I will move it there.

Answer (score 1):

You should setup Room Lists, for example

```
 New-DistributionGroup -Name "Conference Rooms" –PrimarySmtpAddress "ConfRooms@email.com" –RoomList
```

Add your Rooms with `Add-DistributionGroupMember`

Outlook will automatically detect Room List Distribution Groups and populates the Room Finder with room lists in Outlook when an end user is setting up a meeting. For more information check the help for `New-DistributionGroup`

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a try and repost this question in superuser. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Thank you for this. While it did create a nice "Meeting Rooms" group and helped populate the meeting location field, it still does not solve the issue of needing to manually add the room calendars via outlook to make them visible in OWA. I've reposted in SuperUsers and will hope for a solution there.